# Come tradurre "clearing the decks and chucking them all overboard"?

Tags: translation, idioms

([Qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) leggo che non dovrei fare richieste di traduzione. Da lì però vengo rimandato a [questa domanda+risposta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic), che sembra ammettere che tali richieste di traduzione possono essere on-topic, purché descrivano un uso molto specifico e mostrino qualche sforzo da parte del richiedente.)

E allora mi sforzo.

La frase completa è la seguente:

> But it would be rash to start clearing the decks and chucking them all overboard just yet, because ...

Le cose a cui si riferisce lo scrittore come quelle che vorremmo ma non dovremmo buttar via sono state descritte, nel paragrafo precedente, come cose che potrebbero sembrare di poco conto ma non lo sono. Ecco il perché della frase in analisi.

Ora il punto è che [su wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/clear%20the%20decks) (per inciso, [anche il Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clear-the-decks) sembra dare la stessa spiegazione) ho trovato che *clear the decks* è una frase idiomatica che significa su per giù *fronteggiare*, mentre nella frase citata faccio fatica a farci rientrare questo significato. Cioè, sono d'accordo che di *clear the decks* l'autore sta facendo un uso figurato (rispetto a quello letterale di rimuovere oggetti dal ponte di una nave o assicurarli ad esso), ma non l'uso idiomatico (anch'esso figurato, no?) a cui mi rimanda wordreference.

Oltretutto, la situazione si complica allorché la seconda parte della frase ha un pezzo, *them all* che fa esplicito riferimento ai *decks* della prima. Da una parte questo rafforza la mia impressione che *fronteggiare* non abbia nulla a che vedere col significato di questa frase (cosa che mi sembra abbastanza ovvia anche dal contesto), ma dall'altra pone un dubbio di natura logica: se *clearing the decks* significa *sgombrare il ponte/i ponti della nave* (e [da wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponte_(nautica)) mi sembra di capire che ci possa essere più di un ponte), vuol dire che li si sta ripulendi di *qualcosa*, e quel *qualcosa* è ciò che si potrebbe o meno buttare fuori bordo, mentre la frase in inglese usa *them all*, come se uno stesse buttando fuori bordo... i ponti stessi?

Comment: Poi: io evito wordreference come la peste. Spesso è mal fatto, fuorviante, forse generato automaticamente... In particolare “fronteggiare” non c'entra niente. Hai (in forma cartacea o digitale) un vero dizionario inglese-italiano? Io uso il Ragazzini, ma ce ne sono altri buoni. Alla voce _to clear_ c'è tra le altre cose proprio l'espressione _clear the decks_.

Comment: Capisco i tuoi problemi (anch'io traduco), ma le domande in questo sito devono riguardare la lingua italiana. Si può eventualmente trarre spunto da un'altra lingua, ma per esempio per dire “qual è un buon modo per esprimere il concetto così e così (quello che in inglese si dice XXX)”. Qui parte del problema è proprio capire che cosa intenda l'autore con quella frase, e quindi siamo fuori tema.

Comment: Forse su uno degli StackExchange dedicati all'inglese possono chiarire il senso di quella frase, compresa l'apparente illogicità.

Comment: Capisco la motivazione per cui la domanda è OT. Per quanto riguarda WordReference, diciamo che non lo "stimo", ma se prendi una parola qualsiasi te la traduce bene il più delle volte. È vero che cade in fallo in casi come questo. Forse anche molte più volte che altre sorgenti, ma pur sempre in una minoranza dei casi, in rapporto alla totalità delle parole. Ad ogni modo, e per ridere, l'altro link che ho incluso sembra suggerire in qualche modo che "fronteggiare" è ciò che _clear the decks_ ti mette in condizione di fare. Quindi qualcosina c'entra, ahahah.

Comment: Sì, è più o meno la differenza tra “armarsi” e “sparare”: non è che uno è sinonimo dell'altro. :) Comunque, please please please, se fai il traduttore “armati” di qualche vero dizionario!

Comment: @DaG, ho il Devoto-Oli in due volumi. Ma penso tu ti riferisca (anche?) ad un dizionario inglese. Non sono un traduttore di mestiere, ma sto provando a fare una traduzione anche abbastanza ardua, considerando che il materiale originale parla proprio delle lingue. Tradurre gli esempi dall'inglese (quindi non l'oggetto di questa domanda), lo capisco ora, è talvolta impossibile. Talvolta uno deve fare una traduzione strutturale invece che di contenuto, quest'ultimo dovendo talvolta essere cambiato per forza.

Comment: Certo, anche uno o più dizionari monolingue italiani sono utilissimi, ma io mi riferivo appunto ai dizionari inglese-italiano (e possibilmente anche monolingue inglesi). E, senz'altro, in alcuni casi occorre riformulare gli esempi, e più in generale creare un testo che abbia sul lettore della lingua d'arrivo, più possibile, l'effetto che il testo originale aveva sui propri lettori. È la cosiddetta “equivalenza dinamica”. Ma qui stiamo andando fuori tema peggio che mai. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Ma sarebbe avventato iniziare a sgombrare i ponti e buttarli tutti fuori dalla nave*. In questo caso, "clear" è usato nel senso di "packing out", e "chucking them all overboard" si riferisce a "putting them out of the ship".