# Un X è un X è un X - Che cos'è? Si usa in italiano? Perché?

Tags: translation

In un libro in inglese ho letto che *a rabbit is a rabbit is a rabbit*, e ho inizialmente pensato che fosse un errore di battituta.

Ma poi, stimolato da [questo commento di DaG](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/come-tradurre-clearing-the-decks-and-chucking-them-all-overboard#comment34668_14183), ho trovato [questa pagina](https://it.abcdef.wiki/wiki/Dynamic_and_formal_equivalence), nella quale, traducendo le parole di Ghil'ad Zuckermann, viene detto che *un angelo è un angelo è un angelo*.

Di che si tratta? Che cos'è questo *un X è un X è un X*?

- È una figura retorica?
- Che sia figura retorica o meno nella lingua di partenza, è un modo di dire consolidato in italiano per voler intendere che *un X è solo un X*?
- Perché usarlo, se *un X è solo un X* funziona, a mio parere, già bene?

---

Per puro caso, ho notato che in inglese l'espressione è usata anche in contesti che non hanno nulla a che vedere con la linguistica, scegliendo l'opportuno X: [a shark is a shark is a shark](https://dinosaurfactsforkids.com/realistic-was-the-shark-in-the-meg/).

Comment: Sono convinto anch'io che quella di @BakerStreet sia la risposta corretta. Sulla diffusione in italiano per cose che non siano rose, la pagina citata nella domanda non penso che faccia molto testo, perché sembra tradotta automaticamente.

Comment: Sì, l'insicurezza sull'affidabilità di quella fonte mi ha spinto a porre la domanda qui. Ora, però, dato il riferimento all'espressione con X=rosa, mi interrogo sulla liceità dell'utilizzo della locuzione in questione per qualsiasi altro X. Certo, non proprio qualsiasi (perché non mi interrogherei su _un un è un un è un un_)... forse per X qualsiasi sostantivo.

Comment: Non credo che ci sia diffusione in italiano nella lingua quotidiana, è un ambito letterario. Ma sicuramente un traduttore letterario ha la frase di Gertrude Stein nelle orecchie, e credo che gli  venga del tutto naturale una traduzione come 'un angelo è un angelo è un angelo', o cose simili.  Parlo in generale, non so niente di Zuckermann e di quel caso specifico. Naturalmente dipende dai contesti, ma non trovo nulla di strano nel parafrasare quel verso di Stein  in una traduzione. O che qualcuno usi l'espessione in un suo scritto, è come una citazione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È nota in Italia, in ambito letterario,  ed è stata spesso ripresa, l'espressione *una rosa è una rosa è una rosa*. Questa è a sua volta una traduzione di *A rose is a rose is a rose*, che è un verso di un noto componimento di Gertrude Stein del 1913, *Sacred Emily*.

Qui sotto il testo e alcune notizie:

https://dramateatro.it/2016/11/21/una-rosa-e-una-rosa/

http://svirgolettate.blogspot.com/2013/09/gertrude-stein-tra-arte-e-poesia-una.html

Nell'articolo nel link qui sotto si parla di questa espressione e delle possibilità espressive di figure retoriche come  la *tautologia* e  la *diafora*, "una figura retorica che pare ripetere concetti ma che invece amplia enormemente le potenzialità espressive di una frase".

https://aulalettere.scuola.zanichelli.it/sezioni-lettere/le-figure-retoriche-lettere/dire-una-cosa-e-ancora-e-ancora-la-tautologia-e-la-diafora

Comment: Sì. Ma questa figura retorica, come si chiama? Ha un nome?

Comment: Be', è quella che ho indicato sopra, la *diafora*.

Comment: Non è che una rosa (il fiore) è una rosa(il colore rosa)‍♀️(il nome della persona Rosa), è ciò a cui porta, in un parallelo (subconscio indotto), questa espressione?

Comment: Non credo proprio, anche perché l'originale di Gertrude Stein è in inglese, è alla fine solo un gioco di parole derivato da quella poesia di Gertrude Stein.